# Make a dropdown to show with click instead of hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a function onclick for my dropdown menu, so instead of showing when I hover, I want it to show when I click on it, do you know what can I do?

My dropdown is on the grid icon next to "Images"

This is my repo so you can view my code: https://github.com/Diefonro/HTML-CSS

You can also see the page displayed right now at: https://diefonro.github.io/HTML-CSS

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to implement the below function and call it on the `onclick` event. and as @Tom suggested you need to get rid of the below part also from the style sheet

```
.dd-cont:hover .drop-d {
   display: block;
}
```

this is how we catch specific element which has particular `class` and we can change styles of the elements like below

```
function clickDD() {
    const dropdown = document.querySelector('.drop-d');
  dropdown.style.display = dropdown.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

[here is a working example(jsFiddle) from your code](https://jsfiddle.net/sanira/ysr3ukLx/21/)

**ps**
I did not included any assets to the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

To handle the click event, you can take a look at  [EventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) or [onclick attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp).

The dropdown is shown on hover because of this CSS rule :

```
.dd-cont:hover .drop-d {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but how do I replace the hover with the addEventListener? I tried it before but it didn't work since I am applying the hover to the drop-d inside the dd-container.